# Getting PDO Excepetion error while migrating tables

Tags: laravel

I am getting following exception while migrating tables. 
Uncommented pdo_mysql from php.ini file

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu OS or windows user?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Try to comment out `;extension=pdo_mysql.so` in `php.ini` file.

Comment: If you are using WAMP on windows, make sure that the WAMP PHP settings is configured to be using pdo_mysql and myqli. With WAMP, you can just left click the icon in the task tray, hover over PHP, hover over PHP extensions and make sure there is a green tick next to them, the app will then take care of the php.ini file for you.